# fatfree framework, repopulate fields after unsuccessful validation

Tags: redirect, contact-form, fat-free-framework

I have GET route which shows the contact form, and POST route when user submits the form, then in my controller method I do some validation tests on data being submitted.. how would I now send user back to form if data is not valid, with entered data being re-populated in form fields?

I know I can use `isset(@POST.fieldname)` in my template, but what's the right way of
sending entered data back to that view, and how to redirect user back to the
form? Is the `f3->reroute` method right way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take as a rule to include input data inside your form views. This way, any form view will be easily reusable with any source of data.

For example:

**Your form view:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ @@input.email }}"/>
  <input type="text" name="message" value="{{ @@input.message }}"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

**Your controller class:**

```php
class myController {

  function get($f3) {
    $this->renderForm();
  }

  function post($f3) {
    $post=$f3->clean($_POST);
    //validate form data here
    if ($form_validated) {//valid form data

    } else //invalid form data
      $this->renderForm($post);
  }

  protected function renderForm($input=array()) {
    $tpl=Template::instance();
    //variant 1:
    echo $tpl->render('form.html','text/html',array('input'=>$input))
    // or variant 2:
    Base::instance()->set('input',$input);
    echo $tpl->render('form.html');
  }

}
```

In some other contexts, you can feed a form view with data coming from a db mapper (for example when editing an entry from a back-office): `$this->renderForm($mapper->cast())`

Comment: I suppose this is also better for security, having input passed from controller to a view, than using @POST.field in view directly..

Comment: Well I didn't address this point in my example because I thought it was a bit off-topic. I guess it's preferrable to inject the filtered posted data into the view rather than the raw data... although there's no big risk not to do so, since the raw data is not saved in DB at that stage. Anyway, I've just updated the example.

Comment: so now after the user has been submitted valid data, how would one display that form again with success message, preventing further resubmission by clicking f5? should i do `$f3->clear('myformdatafields')`in that `if($form_validated)` block, and then do `$this->renderForm()`, or there is no need to clear variable, just call `renderForm()` without `$input`?

Comment: Just reroute to the `GET` controller. If you need to print a success message, you'll need to store it in `SESSION`. You can implement that yourself or use this [Flash message](https://github.com/ikkez/F3-Sugar/tree/master-v3/Flash) utility.

Comment: can I use native F3, `f3->set('SESSION.message', 'message');`, then after
reroute and display message to the user, clear it in `afterroute()`? Would
that work?

Comment: Sure, you've got the idea :)